# How to get the request header in Struts2 actions

Tags: struts2, request

How can I get the request header in Struts2 actions I can not use `request.header("")` method because in struts2 request is just a `Map<String,Object>` thus this method is not available.

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTTP Referer header in Struts 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1604677/http-referer-header-in-struts-2)

Comment: The "best" answer depends on your specific use case. If it's something you need across the application I'd consider writing a trivially-short interceptor, e.g., https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/struts-user/201010.mbox/%3CAANLkTi=FKyTfAvBhRRj_t0Vj5G5d=W2PHLFzWdqXn483@mail.gmail.com%3E. I tend to stay away from servlet-spec-specific things in actions.

Answer (score 2):

After checking in the internet, I found that I need my action to implement `ServletRequestAware`, which lets an interceptor to push the `HttpServletRequest` in your action. later I can use the same. Thanx all for replying .. :)

```java
public class CategoryAction implements ServletRequestAware{
    // Your code goes here...

}
```